# Checking if $L_1 \cup L_2$ is regular language

Tags: computer-science, automata

Let

$L_1=\{a^n b^r|n \geq 1, r\geq1,n=r\}$

$L_2=\{a^n b^r|n \geq 1, r\geq1,n\neq r\}$

be a non regular languages

> $L_1 \cup L_2$ is regular?

I think that $L_1 \cup L_2$ is regular because we can build automaton like this:

(The double circle is 'Accept')

EDIT:

[image]

> I'm not sure if I'm right

Comment: When you see b, you should move to a final state; from the final state if you see a, go to a dead state and stay there.

Comment: @Aravind I edited

Comment: The empty string shouldn't be accepted, but anyway the language is regular.

Comment: Also, your FA accepts $b$, which isn't in either of $L_1$ or $L_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L_1\cup L_2=\{a^mb^n:m,n\ge 1\}$, which corresponds to the regular expression $aa^*bb^*$ and is therefore certainly regular, but your DFA isn’t quite right: it accepts the language corresponding to the regular expression $a^*bb^*$, i.e., $\{a^mb^n:m\ge 0\text{ and }n\ge 1\}$. You can fix it by introducing a fourth state $q_0$, making $q_0$ the initial state and making it non-accepting, and adding the transitions $q_0\overset{a}\longrightarrow q_1$ and $q_0\overset{b}\longrightarrow q_3$.